# How to handle failed Aggregate in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have a complex registration form on a web application. When the user submits that registration form, then a command is
dispatched to a command handler. That creates an Aggregate. It will then be persisted to a denormalized database and
also an event store. When this transaction is done an event is published. Because of that event another Aggregate will eventually be
created by an event handler.

The registration is only really complete when both aggregates are created. This should happen in the same process, but both
have their own transaction. (eventually consistent)

So in theory it could happen that `AggregateOne` is persisted to both the denormalized database and the event store, but
`AggregateTwo` could somewhere in the process throw an exception because of a bug or validation error (like: *username is required*).

This means that I have an incomplete registration, because only half of the data got persisted. But the user expects to see
all the data he entered.

How are problems like this solved in Domain Driven Design?

---

Note: I don't really have complex registraton form. This is just an example scenario. I'm purely interested in how to solve those kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you describe here as the registration is actually a process. So it has several steps that take some time to happen and must handle not only the happy path but also some corner cases.

As you described, the creation of your second aggregate can lead to errors and so deviate from the happy path.

Because you talk of commands and events I assume you have combined your thinking of domain driven design with the CQRS concept.

For this you need a process manager. If you want to find out about process managers in the context of domain driven design and CQRS you can search for the terms Saga or Process Manager.

A process manager is a simple component that registers to events emitted by your aggregates and send commands in response. A process manager has an internal state to track the progress and decides bases on state and event which command to send next.

Keep in mind that process manger instances have a different life cycle than aggregates although they look very similar. A process instance starts when a distinct event is received and ends with an event some time later.

To make your progress work, you should model your errors also as events. So your second aggregate can emit to a creation command either a SuccessfullyCreate or CreationDenied event. Technically the CreationDenied event could be an exception but easier is it to emit a business driven event instead.

Your process then simple send the command to create your second aggregate, store that fact in its state and upon receiving either or the to possible outcome events act accordingly.

The reactions of process managers to events deviating from the happy path are usually called compensations.

Hope this helps